# Does Spanish have a technical word that expresses changing the shape of verbs?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico

Spanish's verbs change shape. For example:

```
               comer (Standard)
-------------------------------
          (Yo) como
          (Tú) comes
    (Él, Ella) come
    (Nosotros) comemos
    (vosotros) coméis
(Ellos, Ellas) comen
```

Does Spanish have a technical word that expresses this?

Comment: By the way, what you call the **`standard`** verb shape is actually the **infinitive**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Spanish, the verbs have *conjugaciones* — *conjugations*. In your example, you have written the *[conjugación](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AKYxxuC)* for the present indicative of verb *comer*. *[Conjugar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AKbekPp)* —*to conjugate*— means to enumerate or use a verb in all its different forms.

Tip: in the [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?w=diccionario) you can look up a verb (like *[comer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9vPNMxG)*) and click the *Conjugar* button to access every "shape" of the verb for every tense.

Comment: Incluso más técnicos quizá serían *flexionar* y *flexión*